# ERROR al utilizar la FUNCIÓN XMLAGG de Oracle, QUE otra función de concatenación se puede utlizar que no sea "LISTAGG"?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
FROM APLISYS.ASIGNACION         ASI
inner join   
 (SELECT  rtrim(dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(xmlelement(AD,EVOLUCION ||' - ').extract('//text()')
            order by AD.ID_ASIGNACION_DETALLE).getclobval(),1),', ') Lista_EVOLUCION, AD.ID_ASIGNACION 
            FROM APLISYS.ASIGNACION_DETALLE AD     
            INNER JOIN APLISYS.ASIGNACION  AG ON AD.ID_ASIGNACION = AG.ID_ASIGNACION 
            WHERE AD.ACTIVO='S' AND AG.ACTIVO = 'S'
            GROUP BY AD.ID_ASIGNACION)IS_EVOLUCION 
           ON IS_EVOLUCION.ID_ASIGNACION = ASI.ID_ASIGNACION
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-31061: Error de XDB: special char to escaped char conversion
>   failed.
>   31061. 00000 -  "XDB error: %s"
>   *Cause:    The specified error occurred in XDB.
>   *Action:   Correct the error or contact Oracle Support Services.

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo o que otra función se puede utilizar para concatenar cadenas con gran numero de caracteres que no sea "LISTAGG".

Comment: Hola Alexander. Sería preferible que modifiques tu ejemplo a algo que podamos copiar y reproducir de nuestro lado para poder ayudarte. También debes ser claro en cuanto a cual es el resultado deseado, y por qué no quieres usar `LISTAGG`.

Comment: Hola sstan, lo que pasa es que usando XMLAGG y filtrando por el  ID especifico,la consulta da los resultados deseados, pero cuando no se filtra por ID,me sale ese error.  En cuanto a lo de no utilizar "LISTAGG" es por que ya lo utlice y me sale error ya que tiene muchos caracteres entonces recurrí a utilizar el XMLGG y me funciono, hasta que lo probe sin filtrar por ID y me arroja el erro:ORA-31061,debe ser que contiene muchos caracteres,la idea es concatenar todas las evoluciones que tiene un paciente,si de pronto conoces una forma de concatenar deferentes a estas 2 mencionadas te agradezco!!

Comment: Entiendo. Nuevamente, lo ideal sea que incluyas un script que podamos usar como un [mcve], para poder reproducir tu problema y conseguir una alternativa que te funcione.

Comment: gracias sstan, esta fue la solución que encontre en esta página: (https://www.javierrguez.com/oracle-funcion-para-concatenar-resultados-de-tipo-texto-en-una-select/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En está página encontré lo que necesitaba para que concatenara sin problemas cuando las cadenas contienen muchos caracteres en caso de que sean más grande que el tipo CHAR2 se puede cambiar por el tipo LONG, en el siguiente link: (https://www.javierrguez.com/oracle-funcion-para-concatenar-resultados-de-tipo-texto-en-una-select/).